# Unit Tests re-organization

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

Normally we work with one Visual Studio solution that contains the product project and the unit testing project.

Our unit testing project is growing fast (2000+ unit tests) and it becomes slow to load/rebuild and difficult to browse. Consider also that - AFAIK - in Visual Studio 2012 test categories are not visible anymore.

We are thinking to split it in multiple unit testing projects:

1. Would it be possible to load multiple unit test projects in the same Visual Studio solution?
2. What is the best approach when the number of unit tests grows so much?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would it be possible to load multiple unit test projects in the same Visual Studio 
>   solution?

There is no problem about this, you can have more than one unit test project

> What is the best approach when the number of unit tests grows so much?

The first and natural approach is to have one unit test project for each project on your solution. If you have a single project on the solution, maybe that's where you need to start the refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

I create unit test project for every assembly. I think you should group your tests by system or component to which they are related. Achieve loose coupling and high cohesion in your tests. Look at this approach [Structuring Unit Tests](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/01/02/structuring-unit-tests.aspx).

Try to use [NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net/) to better feedback from tests and avoid to rerun tests.